# Override of protected method never gets called on TObjectDispatch

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to extend a protected virtual method of TObjectDispatch. But this method never gets called.

[edited to reproduce the problem].

When I override GetPropInfo and use it in TMyDispatch it works as expected. The overrided method is called. However the overrided method on TMyDispatchItem when created by TMyDispatch (to simulate my real world example) is not called.

```
{$METHODINFO ON}

  TExtDispatch = class(TObjectDispatch)
  protected
    function GetPropInfo(const AName: string; var AInstance: TObject;
      var CompIndex: Integer): PPropInfo; override;
  public
    constructor Create;
  end;

  TMyDispatchItem = class(TExtDispatch)
  private
    FItemValue: string;
  public
    procedure ShowItemValue;
  published
    property ItemValue: string read FItemValue write FItemValue;
  end;

  TMyDispatch = class(TExtDispatch)
  public
    function GetItem: TMyDispatchItem;
  private
    FValue: string;
  public
    procedure ShowValue;
  published
    property Value: string read FValue write FValue;
  end;

  {$METHODINFO OFF}

  TTestForm = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  TestForm: TTestForm;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TTestForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  V: Variant;
  VI: Variant;
begin
  V := IDispatch(TMyDispatch.Create);
  V.Value := 100; //this calls inherited getpropinfo
  V.ShowValue;

  VI := V.GetItem;
  VI.ItemValue := 5; //this doesn't
  VI.ShowItemValue;
end;

{ TExtDispatch }

constructor TExtDispatch.Create;
begin
  inherited Create(Self, False);
end;

function TExtDispatch.GetPropInfo(const AName: string; var AInstance: TObject;
  var CompIndex: Integer): PPropInfo;
begin
  Result := inherited GetPropInfo(AName, AInstance, CompIndex);
  ShowMessage('GetPropInfo: ' + AName);
end;

{ TMyDispatch }

function TMyDispatch.GetItem: TMyDispatchItem;
begin
  Result := TMyDispatchItem.Create;
end;

procedure TMyDispatch.ShowValue;
begin
  ShowMessage('My dispatch: ' + Value);
end;

{ TMyDispatchItem }

procedure TMyDispatchItem.ShowItemValue;
begin
  ShowMessage('My item value: ' + FItemValue);
end;

end.
```

I've actually found a way to overcome this problem by changing the datatype of `TMyDispatch.GetItem` to return as a Variant instead. Like this:

```
function TMyDispatch.GetItem: Variant;
begin
   Result := IDispatch(TMyDispatchItem.Create);
end;
```

And now suddenly the overrided method is called. I really would like to understand what's going on here.

Any more ideas or explainations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Virtual method dispatch in Delphi is known to work. So, if `TExtDispatch.GetPropInfo` is not being executed then these are the possible reasons:

1. The `GetPropInfo` method is not being called at all.
2. The actual instance on which `GetPropInfo` is being called is not an instance of `TExtDispatch`.

If you showed the rest of the code then we could be more sure, but the above options should be enough for you to work it out.

The only place that calls `GetPropInfo` is `GetIDsOfNames`. If your overridden `GetIDsOfNames` doesn't call `GetPropInfo` then nothing else will.

---

Considering your updated code, I ran it under the debugger. When the button is clicked, `TObjectDispatch.GetPropInfo` is called twice. The first time it is called as a result of the call to `inherited GetPropInfo()` in  `TExtDispatch.GetPropInfo`. The second time it is called you can inspect `ClassName` to find out what class `Self` is. When you do that you will find that `ClassName` evaluates to `'TObjectDispatch'`. In which case, item 2 from my list is the explanation.

---

I don't really understand what you are trying to do here. However, I suspect that your problem stems from the way `GetItem` is implemented. I suspect it should be like this:

```
function TMyDispatch.GetItem: IDispatch;
begin
  Result := TMyDispatchItem.Create;
end;
```

There should have been alarm bells going off when you assigned the return value of a `TInterfacedObject` constructor to an object reference. That's always an error. You must assign that to an interface reference.

I expect that what happens is that the dispatch code will use an `IDispatch` if it encounters one, but if it finds an instance of a class instead it creates a new `IDispatch` to do the work. And that's the third instance of `TObjectDispatch`.

Comment: Well, since I can debug in to VCL I'm pretty sure #1 is fulfilled. The #2 is in a complex enviroment since the real world class is used in scripting. However if I override for example GetIDsOfNames this gets called. I've added a method which ShowMessages its class and this says TExtDispatch. Thanks for helping.

Comment: If you are sure that neither of my options applies, then you have found an egregious bug in the compiler. In which case you need to create a simple reproduction and submit a QC report.

Comment: OP probably does not calls inherited GetIDsOfNames in the overridden GetIDsOfNames

Comment: @kobik Yes, that's quite plausible. In which case item 1 it is.

Comment: FWIW, your updated code leaks. Unless you assign `TMyDispatchItem.Create` to an interface then it will be leaked. Or destroyed unexpectedly.

Comment: Thank you David for helping out. Can you from the code above understand why not the overrided version is called? And why it suddenly does when applying the "work around".

Comment: The overridden version is not called because the object is an instance of `TObjectDispatch`.

Comment: Agreed on that. Rephrasing my question. Why is an instance of TObjectDispatch and not TMyDispatchItem when it is constructed with TMyDispatchItem.Create?

Comment: I don't know the first thing about `TObjectDispatch`. I've just answered the question that you originally asked.

Comment: OK, I dug a little deeper. Your repro code results in TObjectDispatch.Create being called 3 times. In other words the instance that you return from `TMyDispatch.GetItem` is not used. I expect that the mistake is that you are returning `TMyDispatchItem` when you should be returning `IDispatch`.

Comment: Are you content now. I'm confident I answered the question that you originally asked. I think I've helped on the second rather different question that you asked in comments and your question update.

Comment: Thank you David, I really appreciate your effort. It's not always easy to ask the right question when you don't understand what's going on.

Comment: Yes, I do understand that. Hindsight is very powerful!